# Send socket data to a specific socket id socket.io

Tags: socket.io

So I'm trying to send data to a specific user (Specific socket ID), I've tried doing.

```
io.to(users[steamid].socket).emit('message', {
        type: 'balance',
        balance: row[0].balance
    });
```

users[steamid].socket is where I store all the socket ids, it just fetches the specific ID I want, however when I do this, it works on the first time but when it fires again it doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The way I'm firing the call is with a function, the website has a countdown and when the countdown is over it calls the function which gets the socket id of the winner and then it gives the winner the data needed, I want to know why this doesn't only works on the first time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it doesn't work the second time, then either the `steamid` is wrong or the `users[steamid].socket` is not the correct socket ID.  You need to do some debugging to investigate those values when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A way to fix you problem would be to save *sockets*, not *socket ids*.

If `user.socket` is the socket for a user, you can then do

```
user.socket.emit('message', { ... });
```

Or in your example

```
users[steamid].socket.emit('message', { ... });
```

Comment: I get an error users[steamid].socket.emit is not a function.

Comment: @JacobF that's because `users[steamid].socket` contains a socket id currently, not a socket. I can't see that part of the code in your question, but you need to update the code which sets `user.socket`, i.e. do something like `user.socket = socket` instead of `user.socket = socket.socketId`

Comment: Then how come when I use io.to it works perfectly fine?  It just works once for some reason..

Comment: Hey, do you think you could help me out?